# How to give an option to select graphics adapter in a DirectX 11 application?

Tags: c++, gpu, directx-11, display

I think I know how it should work - only it does not. I have a lenovo laptop with a 860m and an intel integrated card.

I can run my application from outside with both gpu, and everything works fine: the selected gpu will be the adapter with index 0, it has the laptop screen as output, etc.

However if I try to use the adapter with index 1 (if I run the app normally, that is the nvidia, if I run it with the nvidia gpu, that is the intel), IDXGIOutput::EnumOutputs does not find anything, so I can't configure the display settings properly.

I was thinking about simply skipping the configuration, or using the output from the other adapter - but then there is no way to filter out adapters without real output - e.g. my pc has an integrated card too, but it does not have a monitor physically connected, so using that should not be possible.

I also tried to find what exactly the "Run with graphical processor" context menu button does, but I could not find anything.

Goal is to give the user the ability to select adapter inside the application, his/her choices is saved to a config file, and would be used after restart - but I can't find the way to filter the possible adapters.

Comment: i think i tried this before, and as i remember, i wasn't able to do it. I'm not 100% sure (that's why i post this as a comment), but i think it's hardware related and once u start it full-screen it will automatically switch to nvidia card. Also, u can go to nvidia control panel and set there max performance for your app and it will always run on nvidia card.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You likely have a 'heterogenous adapter' system (a.k.a. NVIDIA Optimus or AMD PowerXPress). These solutions have the driver manipulate the default adapter and the device enumeration to control which card is used. You really don't have any programmatic control over this, but you can inject something into your Win32 'classic' desktop application which will encourage the driver to select the discrete part:

```
// Indicates to hybrid graphics systems to prefer the discrete part by default
extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) DWORD NvOptimusEnablement = 0x00000001;
    __declspec(dllexport) int AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 1;
}
```

**UPDATE** With Windows 10 April 2018 Update (17134) or later, you can use the DXGI 1.6 interface `EnumAdapterByGpuPreference`. See [GitHub](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-vs-templates/blob/master/d3d11game_win32_dr/DeviceResources.cpp) for some example usage.

Comment: It works indeed.
Too bad that I can't give the choice to the user directly.

Anyway if he force-starts it with the integrated one it is still used, so if someone really knows what he is doing he can still do that. I guess it will be fine then.

Thanks for your reply :)