# Why my second adapter does not show up?

Tags: winapi, graphics, directx, gpu, amd-processor

Being bogged with the fact that few of the games and graphics applications run in my GPU (AMD Radeon 6600M) choosing instead the Intel HD3000, I wrote this small code to start investigating.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <DXGI.h>

int enumGraphicsAdapters( void* pFactory )
{
    int rc = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    HRESULT rcDx;
    UINT i = 0;

    IDXGIAdapter* pAdapter;
    IDXGIFactory* localFactory = (IDXGIFactory*)pFactory;
    DXGI_ADAPTER_DESC desc;

    rcDx = localFactory->EnumAdapters(i, &pAdapter);
    while( rcDx != DXGI_ERROR_NOT_FOUND )
    {
        if( S_OK == rcDx )
        {
            HRESULT rcGetDesc = pAdapter->GetDesc( &desc );
            if( SUCCEEDED( rcGetDesc ) )
            {
                wprintf(TEXT("Adapter %d: [%s]\n"), i, desc.Description);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            wprintf(TEXT("No more adapters\n"));
        }

        i++;
        rcDx = localFactory->EnumAdapters(i, &pAdapter);
    }

    return rc;
}

int initDx( void )
{
    int rc = (-1);
    IDXGIFactory* pFactory;
    HRESULT rcDx = CreateDXGIFactory(__uuidof(IDXGIFactory), (void**)&pFactory);

    if( SUCCEEDED( rcDx ) )
    {
        printf("Succedded creating DXGIFactory!\n");
        rc = enumGraphicsAdapters( pFactory );
        getchar();
        rc = ERROR_SUCCESS;
    }

    if( pFactory )
    {
        pFactory->Release();
    }

    return rc;
}



int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    (void)initDx();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now, device manager shows up correctly. See image.
[image: Device Manager Graphics Adapters]

But my own code does not detect the AMD Radeon Graphic adapter. See image.

[image]

Could someonde explain me why this is happening?

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have an AMD PowerXPress system? See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44174859/how-to-give-an-option-to-select-graphics-adapter-in-a-directx-11-application/44184417#44184417)

Comment: I will say your code enumerates three adapters on my system, an Intel, an AMD and the Microsoft basic render driver.

Comment: As this only appears to happen on certain hardware configurations, it would be helpful if you disclosed information about the machine you are running your test code on (brand, model, configuration).

Comment: This probably won't solve the issue, but note, enumGraphicsAdapters is leaking adapters.